# Div positioning on same line

Tags: html, css

I have a problem with some divs. In short here is what I need: 2 divs with a certain width (same width) - one with float left and one with right, and a third div that takes all the remaining space. The divs are using display : inline-block to have them on same line.

I have tried this :

```
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div class="control leftControl"></div>
        <div class="display"></div>         
        <div class="control rightControl"></div>
    </div>
```

And here is my css:

```
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-width: 960px;
    background-color: #E8E8E8;
}

.control {
    width: 10%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #ADADAD;
}

.leftControl {
    float: left;
}

.rightControl {
    float: right;
}

.display {
    width: 80%;
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

The problem is that using % on some resolution causes the last div (controlRight) to be moved on a new line.I can understand why and found that if i use 79% on display the divs display almost correctly (1% left unsued.)
It is clear to me that this is not a correct solution.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is it necessary to set width of .display to 80%? As i can understand, it'll work without width expanding to fit its content.

Comment: There must be a certain amount of browser oddness going on here. OP code works exactly as desired (for me) in FF 16.0.2, IE9 and Opera 12.02, but does not work in Safari 5.1.7 and Chrome 23.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put all your elements `float:left` and your 100% will always fit: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/f39zH/)

HTML

```
<div class="control"></div>
<div class="display"></div>         
<div class="control"></div>
```

CSS

```
.control {
    width: 10%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: green;
    float:left;
}

.display {
    width: 80%;
    height: 200px;
    background-color:blue;
    float:left; 
}​
```

Putting everything on `float left` will simply push divs one by one on the right.